# Error: Type 'Promise<AxiosResponse<void, any>>' is not assignable to type 'AnyAction'

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to implement adding backends to my project through browser. Delete function works good, but with add function I have a problem, which I can't solve.

**Error:**

```
     Type 'Promise<AxiosResponse<void, any>>' is not assignable to type 'AnyAction'.
    38 |     const handleAdd = (e: FormEvent) => {
    39 |         e.preventDefault();
  > 40 |         dispatch(addServer({url, healthCheckTcpTimeout, maximalRequests}));
       |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    41 |     }
```

**Main.tsx:**

```
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
    const handleAdd = (e: FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(addServer({url, healthCheckTcpTimeout, maximalRequests}));
    }
```

**index.ts**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import authReducer from './auth/authReducer'
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

import logger from 'redux-logger'


export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(...(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? [logger] : [])),
})


export type IRootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch // Export a hook that can be reused to resolve types
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<IRootState> = useSelector
```

**actionCreators.ts:**

```
export const addServer = (data: IServerConfig) =>
    async (dispatch: Dispatch<any>): Promise<void> => {
        const log = await api.auth.addServer(data)
        const res = await api.auth.getServers()
        dispatch(loadAddServer(data))
        dispatch(loadServerData(res.data))
        console.log(log)
    }
```

Why I have an error here?

Comment: Why not use [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) since you are using RTK?